# Which family to use for GLMM with 3-level categorical response variable in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, glmm

I'm building a model with a 3-level categorical response variable and both fixed and random effects to analyze data from a survey of volunteers. My response variable ('wellbeing', self-reported) has the levels 'no change', 'improved', and 'declined'. I have multiple predictor variables including, e.g., hours per month spent volunteering. I'm thinking I need something like this:

```
m <- glmer(wellbeing ~ hours.month + region + age + (1|participantID), data=vol.data)
```

However, I don't know what to use for family and link because it seems that the binomial family is just used for 2-level categorical responses. Would the following work, or does I need something else since I have a 3-level categorical response?

```
m <- glmer(wellbeing ~ hours.month + region + age + (1|participantID), 
           data=vol.data, family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280423/is-it-currently-possible-to-run-a-multinomial-logistic-regression-with-random-su

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dependent variable appears to be ordinal - that is, categorical with a natural ordering in the sense that `declined` is "less than" `no change` and `no change` is "less than" `improved`

`lme4` does not handle ordinal responses. Instead you can use `MCMCglmm` or `clmm` from the `ordinal` package. Using the latter, you would fit a model like this:

```
m1 <- clmm(wellbeing ~ hours.month + region + age + (1|participantID), 
       data=vol.data, link = "probit", threshold = "equidistant")
```